# Dynamic id add to class name in Jquery MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to add the dynamic id into the JQuery selector click event. I have looked some other solutions but it did not work.

My code is  -

```
@Html.ActionLink(Model.link, "Default", "Default", null, new { @class = "btnclick"+classid, onclick = "return false;" })

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var tmpValues = '';
        tmpValues = $('this').attr('class');
        $('.btnclick'+tmpValues).click(function () {
            $(this).closest('form')[0].submit();
        });
    });                                              
</script>
```

Comment: What makes you think you need to _add a dynamic id_?

Comment: _I have looked some other solutions_.....doesn't seem to be.

Comment: @StephenMuecke, I have many links, so when I am submitting the link, I need to know which link is submitted

Comment: Nothing in your code will indicate which link is clicked! And your script submits a form (it does not make a redirect). What is it that you really trying to do?

Comment: @StephenMuecke, when I am submitting the link I want the link will be unique because there are many links in the page

Comment: You not submitting a link. your submitting a form!

Comment: @StephenMuecke, sorry, you are right, I need to know which link is clicked

Comment: You already know which link was was clicked - is `$(this)` and how many forms do you really have in your view. And why are you using a link (which is for redirecting). Your code is not making sense.

Comment: @StephenMuecke, I am new in Jquery, I have lots of forms, and its increasing every time, thats why I need to add the dynamic class ID

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118014/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-arifpervez).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly,Do not use class name that are unique,instead use an id if you really want to proceed with your logic.I think there is a pretty straight forward way to do this.Instead of returning false on click assign a function.

```
@Html.ActionLink(Model.link, "Default", "Default", null, new {id="1",  onclick = "myfunc();" })
```

Now myFunc code goes as below,does the trick

```
 function myfunc()
    {
       var myid=this.attr("id");
       switch(myid){
         case "1":
        //dom manipulations for this id
        break;  
       }      
    }


   $(this).closest('form')[0].submit();
}
```

And if want to manipulate dom depending which button is clicked then add an id attribute to event action link and get the id and have a switch case where you can manipulate any dom specific to the button.
Now on click of all links you can call the above function.This would be very easy to achieve.

Comment: Good to hear ,that it helped you.. :)